# django 1.9 not creating table for custom user model

Tags: python, django, django-users

My project name is timecapture

Here is relevant portion of timecapture/settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [ 
        # 'django.contrib.admin',
        'django.contrib.auth',
        'django.contrib.contenttypes',
        'django.contrib.sessions',
        'django.contrib.messages',
        'django.contrib.staticfiles',
        'timecapture',
        'timesheet'
        ]

AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'timecapture.TimeUser'
```

And here is timecapture/models.py

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser
)
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.db import models
from django.utils import timezone

class TimeUserManager(BaseUserManager):
    use_in_migrations = True
    def create_user(self, email, password=None):
        """
            Creates and saves a User with the given email, date of
            birth and password.
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address')

        user = self.model(
                email=self.normalize_email(email),
                )

        user.set_password(password)
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user  

    def create_superuser(self, email,  password):
        """
            Creates and saves a superuser with the given email, date of
            birth and password.
        """
        user = self.create_user(email,
                password=password,
                )
        user.is_staff = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user          

class TimeUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    email = models.EmailField(
            verbose_name='email address',
            max_length=255,
            unique=True,
            )
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
            _('active'),
            default=True,
            help_text=_(
                'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. '
                'Unselect this instead of deleting accounts.'
                ),
            )
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    first_name = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    is_staff = models.BooleanField(
            _('staff status'),
            default=False,
            help_text=_('Designates whether the user can log into this admin site.'),
            )
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()
    objects = TimeUserManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = _('TimeUser')
        verbose_name_plural = _('TimeUsers')
        abstract = False
        db_table = 'timeuser'
        app_label = 'timecapture'

    def get_full_name(self):
        """
        Returns the first_name plus the last_name, with a space in between.
        """
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        "Returns the short name for the user."
        return self.first_name


    def __str__(self):              
        return self.email

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        "Does the user have a specific permission?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        "Does the user have permissions to view the app `app_label`?"
        # Simplest possible answer: Yes, always
        return True

    def email_user(self, subject, message, from_email=None, **kwargs):
        """
        Sends an email to this User.
        """
        send_mail(subject, message, from_email, [self.email], **kwargs)

    @property
    def is_staff(self):
        "Is the user a member of staff?"
        # Simplest possible answer: All admins are staff
        return self.is_staff
```

The tables in db after running fresh migrate are:

```
| Tables_in_timecapture  |
+------------------------+
| auth_group             |
| auth_group_permissions |
| auth_permission        |
| django_content_type    |
| django_migrations      |
| django_session         |
```

I have played around with class meta settings in my timeuser model, but none of them gave any different results. When I try to create user or super user it gives error:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'timecapture.timeuser' doesn't exist")
```

Comment: Did you do makemigrations and migrate?

Comment: @AswinMurugesh yes, I even dropped and recreated my database few times to test it thorough.

Comment: @AswinMurugesh Hi, Instead of running `python manage.py makemigrations`, I tried `python manage.py makemigrations timecapture` and it created the migration. How did that happen ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
python manage.py makemigrations
```

Instead of above when I tried

```
python manage.py makemigrations timecapture
```

It created the migration for custom user model